# Flowable 6, how to get comand context

Tags: activiti, bpmn, flowable

I am a newbie to Flowable 6, when I call Context.getCommandContext(), in some cases it return a null object.

My question is that which conditions are needed to have a command context?. And in my case, if it is null, can I manually add one. If yes, how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Context` API is an internal Flowable API and users are advised not to use that API.

You should not manually add a context, that is handled by the Flowable command context execution.

When invoking your logic in a `Command` then the `Context.getCommandContext()` will not be null.

What I would suggest is to do something like:

```
managementService.executeCommand(commandContext -> {

    // Do something with the commandContext here

}
```